# Input string was not in a correct format?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I want to display data in gridview based on check box selection from another grid view. The given below code getting an error. The error is `Input string was not in a correct format` . Help me to find a proper solution. Thank you.

Code :

```
protected void btnAssign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    Dictionary<int, string> selectedEmployees = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
       {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
               CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[2].FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox);
               if (chkRow.Checked)
                {
                      selectedEmployees.Add(int.Parse(row.Cells[0].Text), row.Cells[1].Text); // error
                }

            }

        }

       if (selectedEmployees.Any())
        {
            GridView2.DataSource = selectedEmployees;
        }
   }
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeID" HeaderText="Employee ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="EmployeeID" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="Employee Name" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="FirstName" />


<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" SortExpression="Select">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

---

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server"> </asp:GridView>
```

DB:

```
[EmployeeID]        NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[FirstName]         NVARCHAR (150) NULL,
```

The given below image is showing data in grid view based on drop-down selection. After that I want to select some rows and click assign then I have to display the selected rows in new gridview.

Image :

[image]

Comment: row.Cells[0].Text' format looks like STAFF****,it can't be converted to int
selectedEmployees.Add(int.Parse(row.Cells[0].Text), row.Cells[1].Text);

Comment: @Phenix_yu : Then how can I solve this error. If I use like this selectedEmployees.Add(row.Cells[0].Text, row.Cells[1].Text); also getting an error.  The error is : The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int,string>.Add(int, string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: selectedEmployees's type is Dictionary<int, string>.you can change it to Dictionary<string,string>,then you can use selectedEmployees.Add(row.Cells[0].Text, row.Cells[1].Text)

Answer (score 1):

You are parsing the `STAFF0023` to int

```
int.Parse(row.Cells[0].Text)
```

which result in the error `'Input string was not in a correct format'`

Comment: If I use like this selectedEmployees.Add(row.Cells[0].Text, row.Cells[1].Text); It shows an error. The error is :  The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int,string>.Add(int, string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Dictionary takes generic key and Value, why you are not trying with Dictionary<string, string>